# How to control opening multiple dialogs

Tags: angular, dialog, angular-material

I have created modal dialog in angular 2 using angular Material UI.
App has two buttons, when we click any button the dialog should open. I am able to open modal dialog on button click but multiple dialog are opened when we continuously click on button.
How we can do opening only one dialog and restricting the app to open another dialog if one is already present.

Below is the APP link

[Angular 2 App](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y8l9fz?file=app/comment-dialog.html)

Comment: Set Background Opacity. So that at a time only one Modal will be available.

Answer (score 23):

```
if(this.dialog.openDialogs.length==0){
   dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalComponent, {
    // disableClose: true  
  });
```

this can be useful to remove multiple opening dialogs

Comment: But what if you have array with some messages to show in dialogs, and want to show next dialog only when previous was closed?

Answer (score 7):

My solution was add dialogRef like a scope variable and check if is null to prevent open multiple dialogs. check here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-js6t7b?file=app/app.component.ts

```ts
dialogRef: MdDialogRef<CommentDialogComponent>;

open(){
  if(this.dialogRef == null){
   //do the thing
 }
}
```

because when you click on one of buttons you created a new dialogRef.

Comment: This does not always work. I was doing this before and then somehow two dialogs were popping up. Shikha Agarwal's solution is better, imo.

Comment: This doesn't work for me either. I'm opening dialogs based on a subscription to an observable, and it seems the subscription fires more quickly than the `dialogref` is updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can add href to referance the open state from different component and disable the open on certain state, Here is the working link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yttuya?file=app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

just check if the reference for the dialog window exists. 
if it does exists, it means dialog window is already open and just return from the func and it won't open again.

```
 openDialogWindowFunc(){
// make sure dialog wont open more than once 
    if (this.communicationRef) {
      return;
    }

    this.communicationRef = this.dialog.open(CommunicationComponent, {
      panelClass: 'recipients-popup',
      width: '555px',
      maxHeight: 606,
      position: { top: '60px', left: '60px' }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following approach to prevent opening multiple angular material dialogs.
On button click/any event (Ex-open(){}) add following condition :-

```
    open(e) {
    
    if(this.dialog.openDialogs && this.dialog.openDialogs.length > 0){
      return false;
    }
    let dialogRef: MdDialogRef<ExampleDialogComponent> = this.dialog.open(
      ExampleDialogComponent
    );
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
      dialogRef = null;
      //add code to perform any other actions on pop-up close.
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to disable the button after the first click so that no subsequent clicks occur something like this

**Template**

```html
<button md-raised-button color="primary" (click)="open('first')" [disabled] = "first"> Open first dialog</button>
<button md-raised-button color="primary" (click)="open('second')" [disabled] = "second">Open second dialog</button>
```

**Component**

```ts
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular 4';
  first = false;
  second = false;
  constructor(public dialog : MdDialog) {}

  open(event) {
    if (event === "first") {
      this.first = true;
      this.second = false;
    } else {
      this.first = false;
      this.second = true;
    }

    let dialogRef: MdDialogRef<CommentDialogComponent> = this.dialog.open(CommentDialogComponent);
    dialogRef.componentInstance.invoiceItemComments = [
      {
        comments: 23,
        createdBy: "NO2",
        createdDate: 1.4
      }, {
        comments: 23,
        createdBy: "NO2",
        cvreatedDate: 1.4
      }, {
        comments: 23,
        createdBy: "NO2",
        createdDate: 1.4
      }
    ];
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      dialogRef = null;
      this.first = false;
      this.second = false;
    });
  }
}
```

> Note - If you have multiple buttons you can pass the `$event` and from
>   there get which button is clicked and act for disability accordingly

StackBlitz working [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aav7r8?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)